# No network manager after an upgrade to Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, 14.04, lubuntu, software-installation

Hello, I upgraded from Lubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 and it got rid off my network manager I added it back to my tool bar but it doesn’t show other networks available. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you start the network manager from the terminal?  This is a known bug   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxpanel/+bug/1308348

Answer (score 1):

If you read the bug report that was mentioned in the comment about you will find that there were two occasions that repaired the problem in some instances:

1. Start the network manager from the terminal.
2. Manually adding `@nm-applet` to `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`.

One of these two methods appear to have worked for some people at least.

I had the same problem when I did a fresh install of Lubuntu 14.04.  I solved it by navigating to Menu->Preferences->Default applications for LXSession->Autostart.  I added nm-applet, exited, and rebooted.  It has worked like a charm since.

Comment: yes when i did this it  didnt do a thing and how do i open it in the terminal i am willing to try that step but i dont know how to open the network manager in the terminal i did it the way you said with the default applications for lx session auto start all i got was the network manager in the top right hand corner but i still cant see the other networks availiable